# Issue with updating a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table

[image]

What I want to do is that Select the `attr_id` WHERE a DISTINCT `name_en-GB` appears and then SET that selected `attr_id` for that `name_en-GB`

I can do this by writing individual queries but I want to know is there any way I can do this in one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally done this

```
   UPDATE sc_product_phrase
    JOIN (
        SELECT
            `caption`,
            min(design_phrase_id) AS minai,
            required
        FROM
            sc_product_phrase WHERE LENGTH(`options`) < 1
        GROUP BY
            `caption`
    ) tt ON sc_product_phrase.`caption` = tt.`caption`
    AND sc_product_phrase.required = tt.required
    SET design_phrase_id = tt.minai
    WHERE
        sc_product_phrase.design_phrase_id <> tt.minai
    AND LENGTH(
        sc_product_phrase.`options`
    ) < 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```sql
UPDATE table1
   SET attr_id = CASE `name_en-GB` WHEN 'Bride Name' THEN 142
                                   WHEN 'Child Grade' THEN 270 END
 WHERE `name_en-GB` IN('Bride Name', 'Child Grade')
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d65eb/1)** demo

Comment: what good is the WHERE? I was about to post the same thing without the where.. not sure why you need it though.

Comment: @JohnRuddell To affect **only** required rows

Comment: Without the `WHERE` or an `ELSE attr_id`, the non-matched rows would all get set NULL.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski yes, if you just add ESLE attr_id, instead of doing the IN() it would be MUCH faster :)

Comment: @peterm see [**Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1d8486/1), you should change your answer to this.

Comment: @JohnRuddell *...if you just add ESLE attr_id, instead of doing the IN() it would be MUCH faster...*.  1. It **won't be** faster 2. You might have unwanted side effects (e.g. if you have a trigger) because you'd update values in every single row

Comment: Sorry for being late cox it was late night in my country.

@peterm your answer is good but I have to put attr_id hard-coded everywhere

Comment: Please see my updated question...

Is there anyway to automate that thing..

Select the `attr_id` where **Bride Name** appears first time and then update `attr_id` everywhere where **Bride Name** appears.

Comment: @user3934473 you need to define what the first appearance of a row is.. is it by the smallest product id number? there has to be some ground for that because mysql has no inherent ordering... a select can return the rows order in any way it wants to unless you specify the order

Comment: @peterm the OP wants to update all records regardless

Answer (score 0):

you can do this simply with an update query and a select.. however I don't know what is the criteria for the first appearence of an attr_id

assumption - first appearance is by the smallest attr_id

```
UPDATE table t,
(   SELECT MIN(attr_id), `name_en-GB`
    FROM table
    GROUP BY `name_en-GB`
) t1
SET t.attr_id = t1.attr_id
WHERE t1.`name_en-GB` = t.`name_en-GB`
```